# PHPMYADMIN Syntax for find and replace with single and double quotes

Tags: replace, phpmyadmin

Can someone help me understand why I am getting a syntax error for this PHPMyAdmin query? A developer did a find and replace for window popups and it truncated the replacement on hundreds of pages to 'onclick="return false;"' by mistake. Full code needed in in the replacement field below.

```
UPDATE `r61bq_content` SET `introtext` = replace(introtext, 'onclick="return false;"', 'onclick="window.open(this.href, \'\', \'resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=no,dependent=no,width=500,height=50\'); return false;"')
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the PHPMyAdmin find and replace:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href,\'\', \'resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=no,dependent=no,width=500,height=50\'); return false;"
```

if anyone needs to know.